# NodeJS crypto.createHmac SHA512 not working as expected

Tags: php, node.js, azure

I'm trying to implement authentication in API request but I am having weird issue with while signing data. The output from crypto.createHmac in NodeJS is different from that of hash_hmac in PHP. I am trying to implement this on PHP and response from NodeJs is what I expected.

Code for NodeJS

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', new Buffer(key, 'base64'));
var digest = hmac.update(salt + '\n' + returnUrl).digest();
var signature = digest.toString('base64');
console.log(signature);
```

Code for PHP

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac("sha512",$salt.'\n'.$returnUrl, $key));
echo $signature;
```

For NodeJS Application I got

```
VZ+gH+BVdZl6GIILfN5TFAxEIUqstiD5YwuQYTdk3R4LSxVzsAXPpPpn5MwHDoRllz5ll5iBpAOuO2DQ9nvtGA==
```

which is expected response but PHP gave me different result

```
NzNlNmFhNWUwOTg2OGQ3NzdhNjU0MWZmOTZhZDZjYmFiYjE4ZjMxZTc5OTk3MDI5ZGI1M2M3YmU3MjRiYTdiNjJmODM4NDA1NmMzNWZlOWE2NTVkZjhmZTg4MDg0MjA3ZmYzMjg1MGQxYzFiZDNkODA2M2MzZGVhOTRiZWMzNTA=
```

which is entirely different than expected. Is there a way I can recreate NodeJS crypto functionality in PHP getting same response.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example, I use node.js and PHP to get signing data, and both of them get the same output. You can take that as a reference.

Code for Node.js

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', 'sharedpassword');
var digest = hmac.update('12345\nhttps://google.com').digest('hex');
var signature = new Buffer(digest).toString('base64');
console.log(signature);
```

Then I get:

```
OTllY2U2NTU4ZWVkYzczZmNlMTQ2YzdlMmI4NjI5MTdhODRhYWNmOGEyNmYzM2M5ZjQ5ZjE1NTM5MjQ1ZDAzYWU1MzlkYTViODY4MjcwM2UyMTA5MjVhMzcyNWJhOWU3OTU3MjY5NWI4ZjkzZGY1Zjg1NTNmYzI3MWU0ZTIyZWE=
```

Code for PHP

```
$signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', "12345\nhttps://google.com", 'sharedpassword'));
echo $signature;
```

Got:

```
OTllY2U2NTU4ZWVkYzczZmNlMTQ2YzdlMmI4NjI5MTdhODRhYWNmOGEyNmYzM2M5ZjQ5ZjE1NTM5MjQ1ZDAzYWU1MzlkYTViODY4MjcwM2UyMTA5MjVhMzcyNWJhOWU3OTU3MjY5NWI4ZjkzZGY1Zjg1NTNmYzI3MWU0ZTIyZWE=
```

Also note that PHP only interprets escaped characters when in double quotes (`"`). So `\n` must be in double quotes!